# Defaulting value of MySQL cell to the value in the previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I was wondering if its possible to default the value in certain columns to whatever the value was in that column for the previous row - via a `SELECT` query.

Kinda hard to give an example of what I mean, the tables im dealing with are pretty big and complicated, but basically Table `foo` and `bar` are related to one another via `foo.order_id` and `bar.order_id`, then theres a `bar.box_id` that contains the box, and doing a *left outer join* on the two will pull some NULL values for `bar.box_id`, so I was wanting to basically default the value in that cell for whatever the previous `bar.box_id` may have been

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "previous row" in a relational database.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: *Maybe* you could deal with this in a Stored Procedure, but quite frankly I think that you're going to need to deal with this in your application code. Simply save, somewhere, "a copy of the previous row, if any." (Default value: *NULL* == "no previous row exists.")

Comment: I don't see any problem pulling this off if you put your mind to it

Comment: Thanks @Drew, you get that from a motivational poster? lol

Comment: Actually I am a big fan of [demotivators](http://despair.com/collections/posters) ... loaded my office hallways up with them. But seriously, if you need help, chat away in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) with us.

Answer (score 0):

## subquery the column

It doesn't sound like your problem is too complex to provide a simple example schema and desired result-set. That said, after several assumptions about what you are actually trying to do (not enough info), you'll have to either fix your data, or run a **very poor performing** subquery.

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    (
        SELECT bar.box_id
        FROM bar
        WHERE foo.order_id <= bar.order_id
        ORDER BY bar.box_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as box_id

FROM foo
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of... having a subquery. That means that subquery would be executed for every row thats pulled... :( Maybe ill just offload this one to PHP

Comment: Your only other option would be to fill the `bar` table with the missing references. Ultimately, that's the right way to handle this situation, as the relationship should be controlled by a foreign-key constraint, for exactly this reason.